# why is the password is not matching after md5 encryption?

Tags: php

md5 encryption is set in the database,then in login.php i use select statement to match:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    include"db.php";
    if ( isset( $_POST['email_id'] ) ) {
        $email_id = $_POST['email_id'];
        $password = $_POST['password'];
        $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email_id='$email_id' AND password='md5($password)' LIMIT 1";
        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        $count = mysql_num_rows($res);
        if ( $count == "1" ) {
            $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);
            $name = $row["first_name"];
            $_SESSION["name"] = $name;
            $_SESSION["password"] = $password;
            header("location:index.php");
            exit();
        } else {
            echo "Invalid LOGIN information.";
            exit();
        }
    }
?>
```

The message 'Invalid login information' is displayed.

Comment: 1) MD5 is not encryption.  2) Do not use MD5. 3) You have a SQL injection vulnerability. 4) **Do not store passwords in plain text** in session. 5) Do not use `mysql_*()`

Comment: You have some very bad codding practice there @user2280276

Comment: Please format code in the future - this time it's on the house ;)

Comment: wat can be used then?

Comment: @vinigarcia87: Don't do that either.

Comment: #1 Append some "security text" before hash, #2 Use SHA1, #3 Use PDO.

Comment: You should use PDO with parameters, and bcrypt with salt.

Comment: @IAmNotProcrastinating: Don't use SHA either.

Comment: But... but... but... :(

Comment: @SLaks We can comment 100 things not to use, but rather comment once what to use, this will help him more

Comment: @SLaks Moreover, beginners tend to use `mysql_()`, PDO will bounce over their head, let them go ahead and later switch to PDO once they get exactly why to use it and HOW to use it

Comment: @Mr.Alien that's all fine and dandy, but in the mean time, please don't let them get near security sensitive code...?

Answer (score 4):

You need to concat your string

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user 
        WHERE email_id='$email_id' 
        AND password='".md5($password)."' LIMIT 1";
```

Or better do it like this

```
$password = md5($fetched_password);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM user 
        WHERE email_id = '$email_id' 
        AND password='$password' LIMIT 1";
```

And you don't have to use `LIMIT 1` as the query **HAS** to fetch unique row else your DB design is not correct, moreover instead e-mail, I use **Unique User Id's**

Comment: [wrong](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/4.1/en/encryption-functions.html#function_md5)

Comment: -1 Why you are encouraging this sort of programming? Maybe should help him fix it.

Comment: Musa: It does, but if he's using that, he needs to put the quotes on the inside of the function, not around it.

Comment: @SLaks What's wrong about it? You can use the PHP way _OR_ the mysql way... And this _IS_ the right PHP way.

Comment: I have you the -1 your encouraging horrible practices with your "solution" offer the OP a new solution and possibly fix it for him

Comment: @RixhersAjazi Can you tell me what's horrible here?

Comment: First off don't insert user input into a query. Second you made no mention of proper password storing. Fix your answer and I'll happily +1 you

Comment: @RixhersAjazi He is not inserting, he is **SELECTING**, secondly question was not about how to store passwords :)

Comment: He's using MD5 out SQL cuz it avoid injection and `mysql_real_escape_string` use :3

Comment: @IAmNotProcrastinating Tell me how to do sql injection with a user input which is md5 hashed before being inserted into the query?

Comment: Mr alien none the less promoting old dangerous functions and bad password storing is dangerous sir

Comment: @bwoebi Users often follow others without knowing actual thing here, like Rixhers said about **INSERTING**, now where's **INSERT** used here?

Comment: But this is what i'm talking about, theres no way to SQL Injection cuz it's outside of the query.

Comment: Okay so Mr alien for every select statement you have I want you to use Mysql_. Would you do that? If not why are telling some one else too do that?

Comment: @RixhersAjazi Read this http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/143379/automatically-warn-against-the-use-of-mysql-functions-on-stack-overflow

Comment: Not only is using Mysql stupid in a security sense, but what happens when php 5.5 congress or and Mysql_ is no more? Let me guess you will revert to pdo or MysqliMysql. Thanks Mr. Alien

Comment: @RixhersAjazi Millions of developers have built their systems using `mysql_()`, some big, some small, it's not possible for a developer to update 1000's of projects

Comment: Not going to read what you have to say Mr alien answer my question with what you would do. Thanks, and sorry for the tone of my words. It's just irresponsible to promote these practices

Comment: your right Mr alien it is not possible, but for new code you should avoid these practices

Comment: @RixhersAjazi Haha seriously you should give it a read :) and you are a student, when you get in corporate world with 100 of projects on your head, you cannot update each and every old projects to new one :)

Comment: @RixhersAjazi Of course you should, but some beginners, take for example me, I started with `mysql_()` I moved on to `mysqli_()` and will slowly reach to PDO, doesn't mean I don't want to use optimum programming, but the learning part is in steps, you cannot hop to PDO if you are a beginner, moreover if a user is learning from some old book or a video tutorial, he cannot switch to other extension, as he is referring to a tutorial which is written in mysql_(), got me?

Comment: The bottom line from my view (I am new) for new code use new technology, not almost dead as of php 5.5. For old ones then you can't do anything about it. I understand where your coming from alien

Comment: @RixhersAjazi Exactly, some people are learning say HTML from start, for a beginner in 2013, he may directly refer to HTML5, it's just like do what you are comfortable with, nothing else, yea and when you get programming grip, that's when you start learning good and bads

Comment: Good to come to a understanding.

Comment: @RixhersAjazi You got my point :) but some really don't care, for todays example, you can read comments here, they are funny stackoverflow.com/questions/16081829/mysql-insert-error-can-not-find-the-issue

Comment: I've also started with `mysql_*`, but then the deprecation didn't exist. Today's newbies _don't_ read the documentation, they're only following tutorials... Now, when PHP 5.5 is being released, nobody will complain about it, because it usually takes 3-6 months before most people upgrade it. And often on hosting server farms, E_DEPRECATED is turned off. Most newbies aren't simply _not_ aware of it and wonder why everybody is saying that `mysql_*` functions are bad... But why? In their _good, working_ tutorials, `mysql_*` functions are used! They can't be bad! ... So, as long as mysql_ exists...

Comment: @Mr.Alien Correct, but this subject is known to very much people, they're only too lazy. And I think PHP team won't remove `mysql_*` as fast, as it is still very much used... The deprecation is here more a `Don't use it, it's not as good, ...` warning. What I also wanted to say related to newbies: they will trust these old tutorials until they notice that something is not working. (There should be a must to update a tutorial in a yearly rhythm (the actual PHP release cycle)...)

Comment: @bwoebi Recently my company purchased a script online, that was using `mysql`, now big systems are not easy to be updated now and than :)

Comment: @Mr.Alien you're making hard work of proving why you need to stop bad practices _in the bud_. It's never gonna get fixed afterwards. Fact of life.

Comment: Could take this to chat now?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email_id='$email_id' AND password='md5($password)' LIMIT 1";
```

Did you already check your mysql table? The entry should be `md5(YOUR_PASSWORD)` instead of the md5 hash...

You cannot inline php-code / put mysql-functions into quotes:

MySQL has a MD5 function:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email_id='$email_id' AND password=MD5('$password') LIMIT 1";
```

or use the md5 function of PHP:

```
 $sql="SELECT * FROM user WHERE email_id='$email_id' AND password='".md5($password)."' LIMIT 1";
```

P.s.: if you use the MySQL way, do not forget to escape your password with `mysql_real_escape_string`!

Answer (score 1):

How about this OP rather then using md5 for password storing why not use bcrypt? There is a great library called password_compat that will do all the heavy lifting for you. Google password_compat.

Next thing OP I would recommend in using PDO rather then Mysql_ functions as they are not supported any longer.

Why do what I said?

Md5 was first implemented for file checking in its early days. Even using sha1/2 is still not enough with the computing power now days. With bcrypt cracking passwords is extremely costly to the system. So please look at bcrypt.

Why use pdo? Because rather then using Mysql functions which could leave you vulnerable to injection you could parameterize your values for much better security against injection. Your first problem is security OP not the logic you are trying to implement. I hope you the best.